# GAM: why mgcv::gam provides different results regarding to the order of the levels of the explanatory variable

Tags: r, time-series, gam, model-fitting

I am trying to get the seasonal trend of two groups of individuals using GAMMs. I performed two analysis changing the order of the levels of the explanatory variable in order to get one plot of the seasonal trend for each level.
However, I am surprised with the output of the two GAMMs because they vary according to the order of the levels of the explanatory variable. I expected that the results would be the same because the data and the model are the same in both occasions. However, as you can see below, the results vary the inference of the data studied.

My database contained the next variables:
Species: 4 levels
Populations: 20 levels
Reproductive_State: 2 levels
Survival_probability: range [0-1]
Year
Month
Fortnight: from 1 to 26 (called Seasonality in analysis)

I am trying to get a descriptive estimates and plots of the "common seasonal survival of the species" checking the existence of differences between the two levels of the variable reproductive_state.

In order to check it I performed did:

```
# Specify the contrast: Reproductive group
data$Reproductive_Group <- as.factor (data$Reproductive_State)
data$Reproductive_Group <- as.ordered(data$Reproductive_Group )
contrasts(data$Reproductive_Group )<-'contr.treatment'

model_1 <- gam (Survival_probability ~ Reproductive_Group + s(Seasonality) + s(Seasonality, by=Reproductive_Group ), random=list(Species=~1, Population=~1), family=quasibinomial, data=data)
```

later I change the order of the levels of the `Reproductive_Group` and perform the same analysis:

```
data$Reproductive_Group <- factor (data$Reproductive_Group , levels=c("phiNB", "phiB"))
levels (data$Reproductive_Group )

model_2 <- gam (Survival_probability ~ Reproductive_Group + s(Seasonality) + s(Seasonality, by=Reproductive_Group ), random=list(Species=~1, Population=~1), family=quasibinomial, data=data)
```

In the first model the output is:

```
Formula:
Survival_probability ~ +s(Seasonality) + s(Seasonality, by = Rep_Group)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.83569    0.01202   152.8   <2e-16 ***

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df     F p-value   
s(Seasonality)                3.201  3.963 2.430 0.05046 . 
s(Seasonality):Rep_GroupphiNB 5.824  6.956 2.682 0.00991 **
```

whereas the output of the second model is:

```
Formula:
Survival_probability ~ +s(Seasonality) + s(Seasonality, by = Rep_Group)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.83554    0.01205   152.4   <2e-16 ***

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                               edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(Seasonality)               5.927  7.061 6.156 3.66e-07 ***
s(Seasonality):Rep_GroupphiB 3.218  3.981 1.029    0.411
```

Furthermore I have attached the plots of the two models:
Group_B_as_second_level
[image: Group_B_as_second_level]
Group_NB_as_second_level
[image: Group_NB_as_second_level]

I thought that the plot of the seasonality should be the same for both analysis, as long as it represents exclusively the seasonality. However if the seasonality reflects the seasonal trend of the other level, the plot 1 of the first picture should match with the plot 2 of the second picture and viceversa, and they don´t do it.

To note, that I followed the blog [Overview GAMM analysis of time series data](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~jvanrij/Tutorial/GAMM.html) for writting the formula and checking the differences of the seasonal trend accross the two reproductive state.

Do you know why I obtain different results with these two models?

Comment: Why are you using an `ordered` and then assigning `contr.treatment`? To the best of my knowledge, the only thing that using `ordered` does is set the default contrasts to compare 2 with 1, 3 with 2, 4 with 3, etc.

Comment: @Gregor To the best of my knowledge the default contrasts for ordered factors are polynomial contrasts.

Comment: Ah, your're right. Still seems weird to use an `ordered` factor and then assign `contr.treatment`. If the `as.ordered()` line were omitted, the following `contrasts<-` line could also be omitted.

Comment: If I am doing what I think, the `contr.treatment` is used for comparing the two levels. If I don´t put it the output of the gam contains the estimates for: 1) s(Seasonality); 2) : s(Seasonality):Rep_GroupphiB and 3)  s(Seasonality):Rep_GroupphiNB. 
This output doesn´t allow to check the existence of differences between the treatments. Maybe it is better explained here: "http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~jvanrij/Tutorial/GAMM.html".